# Highchart range selector doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, electron

For the last few hours I am struggling with rangeSelector in Highcharts. I have enabled: input and allButtons, but that didn't help. Also I've put min and max for x axis and also min range for x axis, still no luck. Here is my initialization of graph:

P.S. dataPreparedForGraph is series of element containing javascript Date, and some value.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
          useUTC: false
      }
  });

  Highcharts.chart('graph', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'x',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift'
    },
    title: {
        text: tableName
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        min: timestamp_label[0].getTime(),
        max: timestamp_label[timestamp_label.length - 1].getTime(),
        minRange: 3600
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Sensor value'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        grouping: false
      },
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        },
      }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: true,
      inputEnabled: true,
      allButtonsEnabled: true,
      buttons: [
        {
          type: 'minute',
          count: 1,
          text: 'minute'
        },{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: 'hour'
      },{
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: 'day'
      }, {
          type: 'week',
          count: 1,
          text: 'week'
      }],
      buttonTheme: {
          width: 60
      },
      selected: 2
    },
    series: dataPreparedForGraph
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range selector is available only for Highstock.

To use it, you need to change source code:

`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>`

and use `stockChart` constructor:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('graph', {...});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mtkcg6aj/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/understanding-highstock

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why series labels don't show up now?